# UITabBar functionality in an object

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Is there an object I can use that "simulates" the TabBar functionality and doesn't need to be in the middle of the screen?

Meaning - an object I can have tabs, put images on them, automatic nice "selection color" and of course run some code on selection

IOS 7 and up is OK

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you're looking for a [UISegmentedControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html).

Comment: OK... looks promising... But how can I make the UITabBar appearance? (images that change color "out of the box" upon selection

Comment: Out of the box, you could use the [UIAppearance](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAppearance). But I advice to check for [third-party components](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=✓&q=segment), you may find one useful. Also, if you were gave more details on your question, it could be easier to answer it.